# MongoDB Aggregation based on corresponding array index matches for a chatting application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I want to implement an aspect of chatting application, i.e number of unseen / new messages for a particular chat.
Here's my chat Schema :

```
var chatSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, default: "friend_chat" },
    chat_type: { type: String, default: "group" },
    lastMessage: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Message',
        default: ObjectId("000000000000000000000000")
    },
    participants: [{
        _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Member' },
        //used to keep track of new messages/messages count
        lastMessageId: { type: String, default: "000000000000000000000000" },
        //status can be admin,blocked,member
        status: { type: String, default: "member" }
    }],
    isDeleted: { type: Boolean, default: false }
})
```

Here's my Message Schema :

```
var messageSchema = new Schema({
    senderId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Member' },
    type: String,
    content: String,
    timeCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    chatId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Chat' },
    isRead: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    isDeleted: { type: Boolean, default: false }
})
```

So the lastMessageId key in the participants arrays basically informs of the Id of the last Message the participant has seen. Therefore, to quickly retrieve the number of unseen Messages for a "single" chat window,how can I do this:

```
Message.aggregate([{$match:{chatId:INPUT_CHAT_ID, 
senderId:PARTICIPANT'S_ID/req.session.userId,_id:
{$gt:participants.index.lastMessageId}}}])
```

For the above what should be the approach for getting the index.
Currently I have just implemented a linear search at frontend which gives me the lastMessageId as a parameter in the request to get around the problem but I want to know what should be the approach here.

Also suppose by linear search at the frontend,I am able to get the index,since frontend also has the copy of chat document(mongodb document) for displaying. Now I want to query the same thing but for multiple chats. Of course using `Message.aggregate` for each chatId is inefficient so what is the recommended way here.Currently from the front end I receive a JSONObject "chats" of this form:

```
`{ids:CHAT_IDs_array,last_Message_Ids :LAST_MESSAGE_IDS_array} `
```

in order meaning that the first index of CHAT_IDs array corresponds to first index of LAST_MESSAGE_IDS array
My attempted,incomplete,appraoch for this problem is as below :

```
`Message.aggregate([{chatId:{$in:chats.id},senderId:req.session.userId,  _id:{$gt : ????}}])`
```

How to possibly make chats.id array index correspond with chats.last_Message_Ids index. 
Also I would be appreciative if the answer doesn't impose any changes to the "Schema". Thanks